# How can I update an iOS 6 app to iOS 10-12 and run on Xcode 10?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to update an app that has a deployment target of iOS 6 to a deployment target of iOS 10. The app will not build in Xcode 10 or 9, but it builds in Xcode 8. When trying to build and run in the simulator in Xcode 10, I receive the errors below. I'm not sure what any of those mean.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/xmmintrin.h:627:18: error: index for __builtin_shufflevector must be less than the total number of vector elements
  return (__m128)__builtin_shufflevector((__v4sf)__a,
                 ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/xmmintrin.h:672:18: error: index for __builtin_shufflevector must be less than the total number of vector elements
  return (__m128)__builtin_shufflevector((__v4sf)__a,
                 ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/xmmintrin.h:849:18: error: index for __builtin_shufflevector must be less than the total number of vector elements
  return (__m128)__builtin_shufflevector((__v4sf)__a,
                 ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/xmmintrin.h:896:18: error: index for __builtin_shufflevector must be less than the total number of vector elements
  return (__m128)__builtin_shufflevector((__v4sf)__a,
                 ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/xmmintrin.h:1609:10: error: initializing '__m128' (vector of 2 'CGFloat' values) with an expression of incompatible type '__attribute__((__vector_size__(4 * sizeof(CGFloat)))) CGFloat' (vector of 4 'CGFloat' values)
  __m128 __bb = __builtin_shufflevector(__b, __b, 0, 1, 0, 1);
         ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/xmmintrin.h:1636:10: error: initializing '__m128' (vector of 2 'CGFloat' values) with an expression of incompatible type '__attribute__((__vector_size__(4 * sizeof(CGFloat)))) CGFloat' (vector of 4 'CGFloat' values)
  __m128 __bb = __builtin_shufflevector(__b, __b, 0, 1, 0, 1);
         ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/xmmintrin.h:1743:10: error: returning '__attribute__((__vector_size__(4 * sizeof(CGFloat)))) CGFloat' (vector of 4 'CGFloat' values) from a function with incompatible result type '__m128' (vector of 2 'CGFloat' values)
  return __builtin_shufflevector((__v4sf)__a, (__v4sf)__a, 3, 2, 1, 0);
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/xmmintrin.h:1995:7: error: assigning to '__m128' (vector of 2 'CGFloat' values) from incompatible type '__attribute__((__vector_size__(4 * sizeof(CGFloat)))) CGFloat' (vector of 4 'CGFloat' values)
  __a = __builtin_shufflevector((__v4sf)__a, (__v4sf)__a, 0, 0, 0, 0);
      ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/xmmintrin.h:2034:7: error: assigning to '__m128' (vector of 2 'CGFloat' values) from incompatible type '__attribute__((__vector_size__(4 * sizeof(CGFloat)))) CGFloat' (vector of 4 'CGFloat' values)
  __a = __builtin_shufflevector((__v4sf)__a, (__v4sf)__a, 3, 2, 1, 0);
      ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/xmmintrin.h:2593:10: error: index for __builtin_shufflevector must be less than the total number of vector elements
  return __builtin_shufflevector((__v4sf)__a, (__v4sf)__b, 2, 6, 3, 7);
         ^                                                    ~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/xmmintrin.h:2615:10: error: index for __builtin_shufflevector must be less than the total number of vector elements
  return __builtin_shufflevector((__v4sf)__a, (__v4sf)__b, 0, 4, 1, 5);
         ^                                                    ~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/xmmintrin.h:2636:10: error: index for __builtin_shufflevector must be less than the total number of vector elements
  return __builtin_shufflevector((__v4sf)__a, (__v4sf)__b, 4, 1, 2, 3);
         ^                                                 ~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/xmmintrin.h:2657:10: error: index for __builtin_shufflevector must be less than the total number of vector elements
  return __builtin_shufflevector((__v4sf)__a, (__v4sf)__b, 6, 7, 2, 3);
         ^                                                 ~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/xmmintrin.h:2678:10: error: index for __builtin_shufflevector must be less than the total number of vector elements
  return __builtin_shufflevector((__v4sf)__a, (__v4sf)__b, 0, 1, 4, 5);
         ^                                                       ~
```

Comment: Are you jumping straight from iOS 6 to 10? If so, it may be helpful to increment the target just one version at a time.

Comment: @NRitH I am. I will try this. Thank you!